# Killing an application started using system() in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to run an application inside a Perl script using `system()`. The application I'm running gets stuck sometimes (it enters some kind of infinite loop). Is there a way I can know if this application is stuck and kill it to continue with the Perl script?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
start testapp.exe;
if(stuck with testapp.exe) {
    kill testapp.exe;
}
```

Comment: "is there a way I can know…" … well, actually, it sounds as though you do have *some way* of knowing that it's "stuck." HOw are you determining that, by hand? Based on the program running too long, or putting out a certain output over and over, or … ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining if "it is stuck in infinite loop" is called [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and is undecidable.

If you want to kill it, you will have to fork the application using `fork` and then kill it from the other fork, if it is going for too long.

You can determine if the proccess is going for too long by this

```
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)>0 #waitpid returns 0 if it still running
```

at least, according to [this manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html)

I am not sure how well it works on various systems, you can try it out.

Not a direct answer, but I can recommend using `forks` module if you want to fork with ease, but it works **only** on UNIX systems (**not** windows).

---

OK, more helping code :) It works in UNIX, according to perlfork perldoc, it should work on Windows exactly the same way.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
my $exited_cleanly;                 #to this variable I will save the info about exiting

my $pid = fork;
if (!$pid) {
     system("anything_long.exe");        #your long program 
} else {
     sleep 10;                           #wait 10 seconds (can be longer)
     my $result = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);  #here will be the result

     if ($result==0) {                   #system is still running
         $exited_cleanly = 0;            #I already know I had to kill it
         kill('TERM', $pid);             #kill it with TERM ("cleaner") first
         sleep(1);                       #wait a bit if it ends
         my $result_term = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);
                                         #did it end?

         if ($result_term == 0) {        #if it still didnt...
             kill('KILL', $pid);         #kill it with full force!
         }  
     } else {
         $exited_cleanly = 1;            #it exited cleanly
     }  
}

#you can now say something to the user, for example
if (!$exited_cleanly) {...}
```

Comment: That is what i'm thinking to do putting some kind of time limit on the execution. Is there a way to find if the child process is still running?

Comment: The [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which is about finding a general algorithm for all possible program-input pairs to determine if an arbitrary program will halt, really doesn't have much to do with what the questioner is asking.

Comment: An important thing to remember, the kill signal needs to be capitalized.  Lowercase 'kill' is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
system("start testapp")
```

is short for

```
system("cmd", "/c", "start testapp")
```

Perl just knows about `cmd`; it doesn't know anything about `start`, much less about `testapp`. `system` is not the tool you want. That's the first problem.

---

The second problem is that you haven't defined what it means to be "stuck". If you want to monitor a program, it needs a heartbeat. A heartbeat is a periodic activity that can be externally examined. It can be writing to a pipe. It can be changing a file. Anything.

The monitoring program listens for this heartbeat, and presumes the program is dead if the heart stops beating, so to speak.

---

"Killing" is done using signals in unix, but it's done using [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in Windows. The third problem is that Perl core does not give you access to that function.

---

The solution to the first and third problem is [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aProcess). It allows you to launch a process in the background, and it also allows you to terminate it.

Creating a heartbeat is up to you.

Comment: The `TerminateProcess` call is built in to perl on Windows -- see `win32/win32.c`.  `kill 'KILL',...` and `kill 'ZERO',...` are DWIM on Windows. But the other signals, not so much.

Comment: That means one could use `my $pid = system(1, "testapp");` (documented in perlport) and `kill KILL => $pid;` instead of Win32::Process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can handle the problem if you know that testapp should not take more than N seconds to do its thing, then you can use a timeout to kill the app by way of [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun).

In the example below there is a timeout of 1 second which kills the `sleep 10` command that takes too long (longer than the timeout of 1 second). If this doesn't do what you want, then you should provide more information about how you can detect that testapp.exe is "stuck".

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use IPC::Run qw( run timeout );

eval { # if (stuck with testapp.exe for more than N seconds)
    @cmd = ('sleep', '10'); # this could be testapp.exe instead of sleep
    run \@cmd, \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout( 1 ) or die "test"; # start testapp.exe
    print "do stuff if cmd succeeds\n";
};
print "more stuff to do afterwards whether or not command fails or succeeds\n";
```

Comment: I have not tested it on Windows, but yes, this solution should work for Windows. The Windows implementation has [limitations](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.90/lib/IPC/Run.pm#Win32_LIMITATIONS), however there are no [limitations](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.90/lib/IPC/Run.pm#Win32_LIMITATIONS) listed that should prevent this simple timeout example from working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine that the application is stuck if you execute it like that, because the `system` statement won't return until the application terminates.

So, at least, you need to start the test application so it can run asynchronously from the Perl script that is to monitor it.

Having resolved that part of the problem, you have to establish a mechanism that will allow the monitoring Perl script to determine that the application is stuck.  That is a non-trivial exercise, and likely system dependent, unless you adopt a simple expedient such as requiring the application to write a heart-beat indication somewhere, and the Perl script monitors for the heart-beat.  For example (not necessarily a good example), the application could write the current time into a file identified by its PID, and the Perl script could monitor the file to see if the heart-beat is sufficiently recent.  Of course, this assumes that the 'infinite loop' doesn't include code that writes to the heart-beat file.

Comment: So could you suggest some other method to start application that could help me to determine status of the application?

Comment: The standard method would be to use `fork` and have the child `exec` the application, while the parent monitors the child.  OTOH, that's the trivial bit; determining what's going on inside the test application from the outside is what's hard.

Comment: A general solution to The Halting Problem would be really useful right about there ;-)

Comment: I am thinking of using the fork to spawn the application as a child process and put time-limit on it's execution. Is there a way to know if the child process is still running?

Comment: Yes: send signal 0 to the child PID. If that works, the process exists. If not, then maybe the process is running setuid to some other user and the original process no longer has privileges to find it, but much more likely it isn't there. There is also the `wait()` and `waitpid()` family of functions. These wait for a child process to die before returning - or for an interrupt or other signal. They do not support a timeout option, so you'd have to code that, but the wait functions mean your monitor process could terminate when the application does, rather than always waiting for a fixed time.